# Javascript pattern for library with dependencies

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Sometimes I've come across a particular pattern present in some javascript libraries. Maybe it's a coincidence but I've seen it in libraries with dependencies. The syntax is as follows (The sample is taken from Backbone which has a hard dependency on underscore)

```
(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
            root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
        });
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
      var _ = require('underscore');
      factory(root, exports, _);
  } else {
      root.Backbone = factory(root, {}, root._, (root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender || root.$));
  }

}(this, function(root, Backbone, _, $)
```

Can someone explain why this pattern is used. The parts I don't understand very well is the use of the `factory` variable, why is testing for the property `define.amd` and why exports is loaded as a dependency in `define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports']`.

I'm familiar with AMD modules but seeing this makes me wonder if I should use the same pattern if I'm writting a library with a dependency or this pattern should be used everytime even if I have no dependencies at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The gist

This is called the [universal module definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) pattern. It comes in countless variations. The core of it is that JavaScript has no builtin module system (up until [ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) become widely adopted) and there are numerous of these out there to fill the gap (e.g. [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/), [labjs](http://labjs.com/)). So the UMD is a pattern that has been conceived in order for your modules to support module systems in multiple environments, since JavaScript is now being used almost everywhere.

## Your example

In your example you will be supporting script loaders that understand the [Asynchronous Module Definition](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD), [CommonJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html) module loaders like the one that [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) introduced as well as plain browsers or other environments that don't expose a module system that the definition is aware of:

```
(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // This branch is to support AMD loaders
        define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
            root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
        });
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
      // This supports the CommonJS module system that NodeJS uses
      var _ = require('underscore');
      factory(root, exports, _);
  } else {
      // Attaching your library root in an environment that has no
      // module system or a system you don't support like a plain
      // browser before ES6 modules become the standard
      root.Backbone = /* ... */
  }

}(this, function(root, Backbone, _, $)
```

With this boiler plate code you can write your module once and at the same time it can be used with different loaders/build tools in the browser, on the server and everywhere else you may find a JavaScript environment.

I suggest you read up on JavaScript modules/module systems to get a deeper insight. [Addy osmani's blog](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) is also a good place to start. There are dozens of resources on the topic.

Hope this helps! Happy coding.